# синтаксические конструкции в gnu/make

Tags: makefile, gnumake

```
include rv32_tests.inc
override ARCH := imfc
src_dir := $(CURDIR)
obj_dir   := $(bld_dir)/riscv_objs
test_list := $(patsubst %.S, %, $(notdir $(rv32_isa_tests)))
objs      := $(addprefix $(obj_dir)/,$(test_list:%=%.o))
test_elf  := $(addprefix $(bld_dir)/,$(test_list:%=%.elf))
test_hex  := $(addprefix $(bld_dir)/,$(test_list:%=%.hex))
test_dump := $(addprefix $(bld_dir)/,$(test_list:%=%.dump))
CFLAGS := -I$(inc_dir) -I$(src_dir) -DASM -Wa,-march=rv32$(ARCH) -
march=rv32$(ARCH) -mabi=ilp32f -D__riscv_xlen=32
LDFLAGS := -static -fvisibility=hidden -nostdlib -nostartfiles -
T$(inc_dir)/link.ld -march=rv32$(ARCH) -mabi=ilp32f
VPATH += $(src_dir) $(bld_dir) $(obj_dir) $(RISCV_TESTS)
default: check_riscv_tests $(test_elf) $(test_hex) $(test_dump)
define compile_template
  $(obj_dir)/$$(basename $(notdir $(SRC))).o: $$(SRC) | $(obj_dir)
  $(RISCV_GCC) -c $$< $(CFLAGS) -o $$@
endef
$(foreach SRC,$(rv32_isa_tests), $(eval $(compile_template)))
$(obj_dir) :
   mkdir -p $(obj_dir)
$(bld_dir)/%.elf: $(obj_dir)/%.o | $(obj_dir)
   $(RISCV_GCC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
$(bld_dir)/%.hex: $(bld_dir)/%.elf
   $(RISCV_OBJCOPY) $^ $@
$(bld_dir)/%.dump: $(bld_dir)/%.elf
   $(RISCV_OBJDUMP) $^ > $@
```

Вопросы:

1. Когда я запускаю `make bld_dir=build`, начинает выполнять правило `default`, а именно его первый пререквизит. Я его релиз не привел, так как разобрался в нём. Далее начинает выполняться разрешение второй зависимости `$(test_elf)`, так? Но в оставшемся коде я не нашёл правила, которое её разрешает. Что выполняется дальше?
2. `define` описывает правило? Почему там используется двойной `$$`? Что он означает? И что означает `|` в списке пререквизитов этого правила?

Answer (score 0):

> Далее начинает выполняться разрешение второй зависимости $(test_elf), так? Но в оставшемся коде я не нашёл правила, которое её разрешает.

вот же оно, объявление переменной `test_elf`:

```
test_elf  := $(addprefix $(bld_dir)/,$(test_list:%=%.elf))
```

тут добавляется префикс, содержащийся в переменной `bld_dir`, к списку, формируемому из списка, содержащегося в переменной `test_list`, путём добавления суффикса `.elf`.

переменная `test_list` определена выше:

```
test_list := $(patsubst %.S, %, $(notdir $(rv32_isa_tests)))
```

и заполняется из списка, содержащегося в переменной `v32_isa_tests` (можно догадаться, что опеределана она в подключаемом файле [`rv32_tests.inc`](https://github.com/syntacore/scr1/blob/master/sim/tests/riscv_isa/rv32_tests.inc)), путём «отрезания» пути и суффикса `.S`.

т.е., пререквизит `$(test_elf)` у цели `default` развернётся в набор строк вида `$(bld_dir)/имя.elf`, а для таких целей правило имеется (`$(bld_dir)/%.elf: ...`).

---

> Что выполняется дальше?

дальше тот же алгоритм применяется для `$(test_hex)` и `$(test_dump)`.

---

> `define` описывает правило?

нет, это просто один из [множества способов присвоить значение переменной](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html). что-то похожее на [правило (rule)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax) внутрь переменной записать, конечно, можно, но чтобы его «выполнить» именно как правило, надо воспользоваться функцией `eval()` (что в данном примере и реализовано).

---

> Почему там используется двойной `$$`? Что он означает?

по последней из ссылок как раз упомянут случай наиболее частого применения удвоенного символа доллара (с моим вольным переводом):

> Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if you really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must write two of them, ‘$$’
>
> знак доллара используется как начало ссылки на переменную, и если вам нужен «настоящий» знак доллара в цели или пререквизитах, вам надо его удвоить.

но в данном конкретном случае этот синтаксис используется для реализации «повторной интерпретации» (это мой перевод термина [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion), не очень, наверно, удачный, но другие мною встреченные выглядят ещё хуже), для хотя бы краткого описания которой «на полях недостаточно места».

---

> что означает `|` в списке пререквизитов этого правила?

так указывается [второй из типов пререквизитов — *order-only*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html#Prerequisite-Types) (обновление которых не приводит к выполнению рецепта для обновления цели). сначала идут «нормальные» пререквизиты, после `|` — пререквизиты типа *order-only*:

```
targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
```